# Storyboards start game button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm looking how to make a start button in storyboards, but it hasnt the initwithnib code to use, like in XLB. I'm using the sprite kit. So far my code is like this.

Viewcontroller.h = mainmenu

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)PlayBtn:(id)sender;

@end
```

And in the viewcontroller.m I want to connect it to myScene where the game is. In the myScene.m.

for that I tried using following.

```
- (IBAction)PlayBtn:(id)sender {
 MyScene *game = [[MyScene alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:game animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Although getting error at the initWithNibName doesnt exist. I have only used xlb before but wanted to make a game with sprite-kit.

Here is a screenshot of my storyboard. All graphics are copyrigth protected. [image]

Cheers!

Comment: take a screenshot of your storyboard and include it in the question. also, mention the storyboard identifier name for `MyScene` `viewController`

Comment: where is the `MyScene` `viewController` in the storyboard? but anyways... since you didn't create `MyScene` with xib, you can simply do `MyScene *game = [[MyScene alloc] init];`

Comment: Don't use the initWithNibName: method, try using segues to trigger loading a new view controller when using storyboards.

Comment: aah thanx, but altough should I add a viewcontroller that is myscene in storyboard? I kind off prefer coding buttons instead of linking them through the storyboard

Comment: The next time make a screenshot with cmd+shift+4 like this it is more anonymized.

Comment: @andrejcurcic : programmatically is good (_till you get a good grasp... logically_), but then xib/storyboard all the way (_but that's just my opinion_). anyways... just drag a `ViewController` object onto the storyboard, change it's **custom class** to `MyScene`, specify it's **Storyboard Identifier** as `MyScene` (_or whatever you want_) and then just go with the flow. Right click on the `Play` button, drag to the `MyScene` `viewController` and select `modal`. that's pretty much it (_plus... no need for that little bit of code anymore_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix and match nib files and scenes from storyboards if you like. If you want to do that, create a nibfile (XIB file) and save it to your project. Then use initWithNibName:bundle: as always.

If you haven't created a nib, that won't work.

If you want to load your view controller scene from your storyboard you have a couple of options.

You can set up a segue by control-dragging from your current view controller to another view controller, naming the segue with a unique identifier, and then invoking the segue directly using the view controller method performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

Another option is to give the scene itself a unique identifier, then instantiate it with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, and display it using presentViewController:animated:completion: just like you are trying to do now.